# Gradle SourceSets Usage in a task

Tags: gradle

I am new to the build tool Gradle and I have defined a source set to exclude few java files. Now, how can I use that source set in my JavaCompile task to avoid those excluded files being compiled ???  Here is my build.gradle and the error.[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4qWM.jpg)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIwu4.jpg)

Comment: I dont understand, the question could you please, clarify.

Comment: Please include a snippet of the Gradle code you have tried, and also describe what the result was. What worked, what didn't work, etc.